# Is this integral improper? If yes - why?

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

Is this integral improper? If yes - why?
$$
\int\limits^2_0 \,\frac{1}{x-1} dx
$$

Comment: at x=1 function $\dfrac{1}{x-1}\;$ is undefined

Comment: **Hint:** Check the definition of improper integral.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Definition:
>
> The integral $\int_a^b f(x)dx$ is called improper integral if:
>
> - $a=+\infty$ or $b=\infty$ or both.
> - $f(x)$ is unbounded at one or more points of $a\le x\le b$.

As @Git suggested verify which ones of above is satisfying the definition. You'll get the answer. ;-)

[image]

Comment: Very nicely argued (just the right nudges needed!) +1

Comment: @amWhy: Thanks my dear Amy. Yes indeed. :-)

Answer (score 3):

It is improper because the function "blows up" between the end points.  That is, the function approaches $\pm \infty$ because the denominator is 0.

Answer (score 1):

An improper integral is the limit of a definite integral as an endpoint of the interval(s) of integration approaches either a specified real number or ∞ or −∞ or, in some cases, as both endpoints approach limits.